# How to realloc shrinking the size of an array?

Tags: c

Example: my array contains integers {1,2,3,4}
I want to resize my array in order to contain {2,3,4} and when I do array[0] it should give me 2.

Comment: Unless that array is dynamic, you're not shrinking it at all. And even then, it will take some work to rotate the content down. Code will be required. Let's start with yours first. We have no idea what kind of array you have (fixed vs dynamic), nor what you've done to try and solve your problem thus far.

Answer (score 3):

When you shrink an array with `realloc()`, you can remove space at the end of the array, but not at the beginning of the array.  Therefore, to achieve the result you want, you'd have to copy the portion of the array you want to keep to its new position and then resize the array:

```
/* setup */
int *data = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));  // Error check omitted
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    data[i] = i + 1;
/* setup complete */

/* Move elements before shrinking array */
memmove(&data[0], &data[1], 3 * sizeof(int));  // Safe move
int *new_data = realloc(data, 3 * sizeof(int));
if (new_data != 0)
    data = new_data;
```

I'm not sure whether a 'shrinking' `realloc()` does ever return NULL (but the standard doesn't say it can't), so the code takes no chances.  Many people would write `data = realloc(data, 3 * sizeof(int));` and run the risk, and they'd get away with it almost all the time.  Note that a 'growing' `realloc()` really can return NULL and you can then leak memory if you use the `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size)` idiom.

Usually, a 'shrinking' `realloc()` will return the original pointer (unless you shrink it to zero size, when it may return NULL).  A 'growing' `realloc()` can often change where the data is stored.

Comment: "I'm not sure whether a 'shrinking' realloc() can ever return NULL" - It can, definitely. Even if you `realloc` a 2M array to, say, 10 bytes, it can very well be there's no 10 bytes free. That is why you should keep the old pointer somewhere safe.

Comment: @tofro 1. If you're shrinking a 2MB array to 10 bytes, then the memory manager ought to be able to carve 10 bytes out of that to use. 2. Even if it can't, why wouldn't `realloc` claim that the shrink was successful anyway by returning the original pointer?

Comment: @jamesdlin Everything that an implementation claims it *can* happen, will happen. On (2): Should a library function return "all OK" when it couldn't do what it was supposed to do? The "return NULL" case is exactly reserved for this ("couldn't do what you want and left the old block intact").